# Database merge issue with duplicate rows

Tags: database, ssis, copy, duplicates, rows

I have DB1 and DB2. I want to export all tables data from DB1 to DB2. Some of tables in DB2 have similar rows as DB1. This throws an error no matter what method I use in SSIS due to PK constraint.
How can I ignore rows that are present in destination tables on the fly and continue copying with others. I need to run the process for whole DB at once. I have 100's of tables so doing for each table will not work. I tried using Transfer SQL Server Objects Task control in SSIS (BI) but it does not give me option to deal with my case.

Any help is highly appreciated and it is little urgent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookup for this.

http://jahaines.blogspot.com/2009/09/ssis-only-inserting-rows-that-do-not.html

Edit: if you need to merger data from two tables, then merge the two data sources using a merge component, then use a lookup after the merger table. If you have duplicates in the merged data, then you can use a sort component between the merge and the lookups and tick the box to remove duplicates. Beware though, that using a sort component is expensive in terms of resource usage.

Another way to accomplish this would be to put all the data from the two tables into a single staging table on the receiving SQL box. Then write a stored proc to insert only new rows into the production table, finally truncate the staging table. I'd call the SP from the control flow as an execute SQL task.

Personally, I'd use the staging table method as trial and error has show this to be simpler and most effective for me. No expensive sorts and lookups required (lookups aren't expensive), but the set based work in the SP is what the SQL engine loves to do.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about LOOKUP control but could not find way to copy all tables through lookup in one run. Is there any control available that allows merge of two similar schema DBs through LOOKUP?